# SD card won't appear after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: mount, 13.10, sd-card

My SD card won't mount when I put it into my lap top,
everything was fine before the upgrade.

The information about the SD card appears just fine when I type 
`sudo fdisk l`  it just says that it doesn't have a valid partition table.

When I type `sudo blkid` I get the following answer:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="CCA8-9030" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="8a1d135b-384b-432d-b608-64dcf09ada24" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="7s6PtU-kj2Z-N8XD-0mzl-840i-i3HG-enlbAf" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Bamboo CD" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="c9b521c8-7c9f-493b-95c8-a7d79c465318" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="7f155ab6-e1b9-485b-a2bc-443c0622284d" TYPE="swap"
```

When I use `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks UVC VGA Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've read the other threads and I couldn't really find any good answers, my card reader was compatible with the previous version of Ubuntu, so technically it should still be compatible with the next version.

Also I can't erase what's on the card, it contains important data which I
need.

If you need anymore information just ask, I'll give it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 13.10. I unplugged my card reader then plugged it back in and it was detected.