# Cannot read my SD card

Tags: 14.04, mount, sd-card

I know that several topics cover the fact that Ubuntu won't mount from an SD card, but I'm trying anyway. I have tried these links, but without any luck: ["Why Does Ubuntu Not Detect My SD Card?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224333/why-does-ubuntu-dont-detect-my-sd-card), ["SDCard Won't Appear After Upgrading To 13.10"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365281/sd-card-wont-appear-after-upgrade-to-13-10) and ["Installed to SDHC, But Can't Boot To SD Card](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197760).

I did not find anything concerning MY Ubuntu OS version. I run **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**, authentically updated with the official image from **13.10**. I have an SD card slot and it used to detect, mount and read SD cards a few months ago when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running alongside Windows 8.1.

[image]

I also got this output from executing `lsblk` in a terminal:
[image]

Is there *any* way this can be done?

Comment: Please post the output of the command: `lsblk` after the sd card is connected.

Comment: On a running system, insert the card and look at the dmesg messages:
dmesg |tail
Is there any indication that the device was even seen?

Comment: Nothing indicates that a drive has been detected, even though the card is connected. I just get weird things on the terminal aout the keyboard layout and other things starting by [41846.676343] for example.